# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with JUnit testsuite error

Tags: spring, ant, junit

I am trying to setup Junit test suite with Spring for the first time and tried with couple of changes in my classes, but no luck and ended up with this error : "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in Myclass"

Briefly, I have 2 test classes both are from same base class which loads Spring context as below

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( locations =
{
"classpath:ApplicationContext.xml"
})
```

I tried adding those 2 test classes into a suite as below

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SuiteClasses({ OneTest.class, TwoTest.class })
public class MyTestSuite extends TestCase {

//nothing here
}
```

I am running this test suite from ant. But, this gives me an error saying "No tests found"
However, If I run the individual 2 test cases from ant, they work properly. Not sure why is this behaviour, I am sure missing something here. Please advice.

Comment: Do you want to try with `@Test` annotation (which is how test methods are qualified since Junit 4) instead of extending `TestCase` (which was prior to Junit 4)?

Comment: Vikdor,I annotated @Test for all of my test methods in those classes. This TestCase class I extended for suite.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you wanted MyTestSuite to be a Suite. Use the `@RunWith(Suite.class)` to run the test suite. The `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)` is needed on test cases where you need get beans injected.

Comment: @Vikdor Yes, I tried that as well. When I tried the above, I get "Failed to load ApplicationContext". But it loads properly if I run test classes individually from ant.

Comment: @Vikdor here is my ant task. <junit printsummary="yes" fork="no" haltonfailure="yes">
   <formatter type="xml" />
   <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
     <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.8.2.jar" path="${lib.dir}/junit-4.8.2.jar" />
   </classpath>
   <!--<test name="com.TwoTest" />
   <test name="com.OneTest" />-->
   <test name="com.test.MyTestSuite" /> 
  </junit>
 </target>

Comment: Do you have the entire stack trace of that `Failed to load...`? I ask because, we run test cases through a suite in this manner where the test suite doesn't carry any spring related annotations but all the test cases are inherited from one abstract test case that has the spring-junit4-runner and context-configuration annotations.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, we run the TestSuite with `@RunWith(Suite.class)` and list all the test cases with `@SuiteClasses({})`. In order to not repeat the `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {classpath:META-INF/spring.xml})` in each test case, we create an AbstractTestCase with these annotations defined on it and extend this abstract class for all test cases. A sample can be found below:

```
/**
 * An abstract test case with spring runner configuration, used by all test cases.
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "classpath:META-INF/spring.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractSampleTestCase
{
}


public class SampleTestOne extends AbstractSampleTestCase
{
    @Resource
    private SampleInterface sampleInterface;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        assertNotNull(sampleInterface);
    }

}


public class SampleTestTwo extends AbstractSampleTestCase
{
    @Resource
    private SampleInterface sampleInterface;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        assertNotNull(sampleInterface);
    }

}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(
{ SampleTestOne.class, SampleTestTwo.class })
public class SampleTestSuite
{
}
```

If you don't want to have an `AbstractSampleTest`, then you need to repeat the spring runner annotations on each test case, until Spring comes up with a `SpringJunitSuiteRunner` similar to how they need to add a `SpringJunitParameterizedRunner`.

Comment: that was the same thing I did initially, I mentioned the same on my first code block that is for base class. The only thing I was missing is abstract for base class, which I added now. But, still seeing the below error. "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/Test"  this is something related to classpath. But my junit task classpath is showing the jar junit 4.8. Am I missing something or my classpath is wrong?

Comment: The annotation `Test` should resolve to `org.junit.Test`. Not sure why it is `junit.framework.Test` in your case. Can you change the import accordingly?